# Inverse cdf of a generalized gaussian distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

What is the inverse CDF of a generalized gaussian distribution?

The cdf is defined as:

$$1/2 + \operatorname{sgn}(x-\mu) \frac{\gamma\left(1/\beta, \left(\frac{|x-\mu|} \alpha \right)^p\right)}{2\Gamma(1/\beta)}$$

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that there is an analytically tractable way to find the inverse *CDF* of a generalized Gaussian distribution (also called **exponential power distribution**). Keep also in mind, that the inverse CDF is often called *quantile function*.

Nevertheless, you could use some numerical tools to solve your problem, for example check the **R-package [normalp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/normalp/normalp.pdf)**, where you'll find the proper function under *qnormp, Quantiles of an exponential power distribution*.